# My `break` doesn't work in while True loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, infinite-loop, break

This is part of my python script:

```
with open("/tmp/IpList.txt", "r+") as f:
    for ip in f:
        page = 1
        ip = ip.strip("\r\n")
        print ip
        while True:
            url = 'http://www.bing.com/search?q=ip%3a' + ip + '&qs=n&pq=ip%3a' + ip + '&sc=0-0&sp=-1&sk=&first=' + str(page) + '&FORM=PERE'
            print url
            with open("/tmp/content.txt", "a") as out:
                content = ContentFunc()
                if "<cite>" in content and "</cite>" in content:
                    out.write(content)
                    with open("/tmp/result.txt", "a") as result:
                        res = CiteParser()
                        result.write(res.encode('utf-8'))
                    page += 10
                else:
                    break
```

When ips in `IpList.txt` are finished it goes to first ip again. Why?

Thank you...

Comment: `break` only exists the loop it's in, not the 'parent' loop

Comment: I don't see how this would happen, unless something happens to `f` in `ContentFunc()` or `CiteParser()` or in the other remaining code you're not showing us...

Comment: @TimCastelijns: The question makes me think that he knows that ("when IpList.txt is exhausted, it goes back to the first IP"), but the question title puzzles me as well.

Comment: @TimPietzcker good point, I have drawn conclusions too fast. Removed my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a while loop, put all ips in a list:

```
 with open("a.txt", "r+") as f:
    page = 1
    ips = [ip.strip("\r\n") for ip  in f]
    for ip in ips:
        url = 'http://www.bing.com/search?q=ip%3a' + ip + '&qs=n&pq=ip%3a' + ip + '&sc=0-0&sp=-1&sk=&first=' + str(page) + '&FORM=PERE'
        print url
        with open("/tmp/content.txt", "a") as out:
            content = ContentFunc()
            if "<cite>" in content and "</cite>" in content:
                out.write(content)
                with open("/tmp/result.txt", "a") as result:
                    res = CiteParser()
                    result.write(res.encode('utf-8'))
                page += 10
```

Comment: My IpList.txt had a problem so my while loop is working good. But your answer without `while True` interested me :) , thank you

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the aboves, you could use:

```
with open("/tmp/IpList.txt", "r+") as f:
    for ip in f:
        page = 1
        ip = ip.strip("\r\n")
        print ip
        loop_going = True # New var <---------------
        while loop_going:
            url = 'http://www.bing.com/search?q=ip%3a' + ip + '&qs=n&pq=ip%3a' + ip + '&sc=0-0&sp=-1&sk=&first=' + str(page) + '&FORM=PERE'
            print url
            with open("/tmp/content.txt", "a") as out:
                content = ContentFunc()
                if "<cite>" in content and "</cite>" in content:
                    out.write(content)
                    with open("/tmp/result.txt", "a") as result:
                        res = CiteParser()
                        result.write(res.encode('utf-8'))
                    page += 10
                else:
                    loop_going = False # Set to false <---------------
```

Comment: This just adds more code without changing functionality

Comment: Just wanted to show: If his "break" doesn't do the job when and where he wants it to, he can use a boolean instead

Comment: But if `break` doesn't do what he expects it to do, the problem is not that `break` 'doesn't work'